# Scraping table contents from a webpage using vba with selenium

Tags: vba, web-scraping, selenium, xpath

My script is able to harvest full contents of a table from a webpage with javascript encrypted using vba in combination with selenium. The table has got a drop-down option from where the full contents can be selected by hitting "all". The table has got 300 rows of data which spread 7 column across. There are around seven steps to traverse to reach the destination page. It takes a while to parse them all. Just run it, sit back and relax until the browser is closed. It works perfectly. I could not manage to create the script with explicit wait cause I doubt there is any option in vba. Here is the working code.

```
Sub Table_Data()

Dim driver As New WebDriver
Dim posts As Object, post As Object, t_data As Object

With driver
    .Start "chrome", "http://apps.tga.gov.au/Prod/devices"
    .get "/daen-entry.aspx"
    .FindElementById("disclaimer-accept").Click
    .Wait 3000
    .FindElementById("medicine-name").SendKeys ("pump")
    .Wait 10000
    .FindElementByClass("medicines-check-all").Click
    .Wait 3000
    .FindElementById("submit-button").Click
    .Wait 5000
    .FindElementById("ctl00_body_MedicineSummaryControl_cmbPageSelection").Click
    .Wait 5000
    .FindElementByXPath("//option[@value='all']").Click
    .Wait 5000
End With

For Each posts In driver.FindElementsByXPath("//table[contains(@class,'daen-report')]")
    For Each post In posts.FindElementsByXPath(".//tr")
        For Each t_data In post.FindElementsByXPath(".//td[@class='row-odd']|.//td")
        y = y + 1
        Cells(x, y) = t_data.Text
        Next t_data
        x = x + 1
        y = 0
    Next post
Next posts
End Sub
```

Comment: `Cells(x, y)` is confusing: the signature for `Cells` is `Cells([RowIndex], [ColumnIndex])`, which means you have `x` for rows and `y` for columns.

Comment: Yes it is. I meant x for rows and y for columns. Thanks for your comment sir  Mat's Mug.

Comment: Yet `x` instinctively refers to the x-axis, and `y` to the y-axis; with that in mind the call would be `Cells(y, x)` which looks uglier, but isn't wrong. Better naming `row`/`column` would fix that though.

Comment: I'll must from now on. I think I should be more careful about naming variables. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good job once again!

I would eliminate one loop depth level - there is only a *single table* that you are interested it - iterate over its rows directly. And, I would switch to more concise CSS selectors to locate table rows and cells.

Also, I would rename `post` to a `row` and `t_data` to `cell` to correspond to what these variables represent:

```
For Each row In driver.FindElementsByCss("table#ctl00_body_MedicineSummaryControl_grdSummary tr")
    For Each cell In row.FindElementsByCss("td")
        y = y + 1
        Cells(x, y) = cell.Text
    Next cell

    x = x + 1
    y = 0
Next row
```

Comment: Thanks sir alecxe, for your review and the comment. It's nice to see that you always come up something new to follow along. Perhaps I need to take a good care of css selectors. I just tested your code and found it working nice as always. Thanks again.

Comment: @SMth80 right, try to grasp CSS selectors - it would be quite beneficial for you in web-scraping. Thanks.

Comment: One request to you sir alecxe. Can you provide me with a link following which I can have a good idea on the basic of css selectors? Please, don't get bothered.

Comment: @SMth80 well, I don't know of the best resource - there is plenty of them on the web. [Mozilla's docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) are pretty descriptive..and practice - open up browser developer tools, the console and play around with `$("css selector here")` function. Thanks.