# Scraping campsite availability from a webpage using vba with selenium

Tags: performance, vba, excel, web-scraping, selenium

I wrote some code to extract the information from a table, but it takes an extremely long time.

The table is in the format of a calendar.
I need the information on an Excel sheet with column 1 as the day number and column 2 as the accommodation type.  On the accommodation type, I only want the “Camp” types and the number of available units to show.
I’m sure there will be a better way to loop through the table.
Any help will be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
Dim driver As New WebDriver, i As Integer, mysheet As Worksheet 
Dim ele As WebElement  
Set driver = New EdgeDriver    
Application.ScreenUpdating = False    
driver.Start "edge"    

driver.Get "http://www.sanparks.org/reservations/accommodation/calendar-month/park/26/camp/41/date/2022-07-01"
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
Set mysheet = Sheets("Sheet1")
i = 7
eRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(7, 0).Row

For Each ele In driver.FindElementsByClass("day")
If ele.FindElementByCss("span").Text <> "" Then
    mysheet.Cells(i, 2).Value = ele.FindElementByCss("span").Text
    On Error Resume Next
    If Mid(ele.FindElementByClass("bold-name").Text, 1, 4) = "Camp" Then 'AccommodationType
        mysheet.Cells(i, 3).Value = ele.FindElementByClass("bold-name").Text & " " & ele.FindElementByClass("unit-numbers").Text
        
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    i = i + 1
End If
Next ele
```

Comment: Related: [Scraping table contents from a webpage using vba with selenium](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/168959/scraping-table-contents-from-a-webpage-using-vba-with-selenium)

Answer (score 4):

If you aren't locked into using Selenium, you can accomplish something similar to this using a web request. Web Requests should be faster as they don't need to worry about rendering any items on screen, they just return data.

I looked at the web traffic, and noticed this site uses an API to provide the data to the front end. I'm using this API, to return the data as JSON, parsing that, then returning that to an Excel range. This takes about 2 seconds on my machine.

In order to get this to work, you'll need a copy of this --> https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON in your project. Follow the directions on the project page to get that setup.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ScrapeCampsites()
    Dim URL As String
    URL = "https://www.sanparks.org/includes/SANParksApp/API/v1/bookings/accommodation/getAvailabilityAccommodationMonthList.php?resort=10&month=7&year=2022"
    
    Dim response As String
    
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .send
        response = .responseText
    End With
    
    'Include https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON into your project
    Dim Json            As Object: Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(response)
    Dim Accomodations   As Object: Set Accomodations = Json("DATA")
    Dim Accomodation    As Variant
    Dim Availabilities  As Variant
    Dim Availability    As Variant
    Dim Results         As Variant
    
    ReDim Results(1 To 2, 1 To 50000)
    
    Dim i As Long
    
    For Each Accomodation In Accomodations
        
        If Mid$(Accomodation("accommodationtypedesc"), 1, 4) = "Camp" Then
            Availabilities = Accomodation("availabilities").Items
           
            For Each Availability In Availabilities
                i = i + 1
                Results(1, i) = Availability("availableDate")
                Results(2, i) = Availability("available")
            Next
            
        End If
        
    Next
      
    ReDim Preserve Results(1 To 2, i)
    
    Dim mySheet As Worksheet
    Set mySheet = Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    mySheet.Range("A1:B1").Value = Array("Date", "Available")
    mySheet.Range("A2:B" & UBound(Results, 2) + 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Results)
End Sub
```

Comment: Out of interest, how did you inspect the traffic, what was the process?

Comment: I used the network tab in Chrome to via the web requests back and forth on the page. I noticed one of the endpoints had `API` in the URI, so I took a peek at what was included in the response. It was the JSON that feeds into the calendar on the page.

Comment: Greedo - I had my vba code checking the availability on IE and not through a webdriver.  This took about 2 seconds to complete.

Comment: Ryan Wildry - Thank you Ryan for having a look.  I have followed the instructions and got the following error: KeyNotFoundError - Dictionary key not found: STATUS  The error is on the following line:  "json_ParseObject.Item(json_Key) = json_ParseValue(json_String, json_Index)"

Comment: @Nelj This is a weird error, I don't see STATUS listed in the keys for code above. It might be related to requiring a reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` the json parser uses this data structure to deserialize the data.

Comment: @Ryan Wildry I managed to get the code running by copying it to a new workbook.  It seems that the old workbook’s selenium reference caused the error (That’s all I can think).  The json converter provides the required information almost instantaneously.

Comment: @Ryan Wildry Is there a way to put a wait to the code, as the webpage is performing a browser check before providing the required information? Sorry I am new to json web scraping.

Answer (score 2):

I notice a couple of things:

1. I found reference that says "Webdriver `Get` will wait until the page has fully loaded before returning the control" so we don't need to wait 5 seconds.
2. `FindElementsByClass` is an expensive operation. We should never call it multiple times if we can avoid it. I've implemented storing the results in a variable to cut the calls in half per loop.

Try this out and let me know if it's any faster:

````
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim driver As WebDriver
Set driver = New EdgeDriver
driver.Start "edge"
driver.Get "http://www.sanparks.org/reservations/accommodation/calendar-month/park/26/camp/41/date/2022-07-01"

Dim mysheet As Worksheet
Set mysheet = Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim i As Integer
i = 7
eRow = mysheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(7, 0).Row
Dim dayClass As Variant
dayClass = driver.FindElementsByClass("day")

Dim ele As WebElement
For Each ele In dayClass
    Dim spanText As String
    spanText = ele.FindElementByCss("span").Text
    If spanText <> "" Then
        mysheet.Cells(i, 2).Value = spanText
        Dim boldText As String
        boldText = ele.FindElementByClass("bold-name").Text
        
        On Error Resume Next
        If Mid(boldText, 1, 4) = "Camp" Then 'AccommodationType
            mysheet.Cells(i, 3).Value = boldText & " " & ele.FindElementByClass("unit-numbers").Text
            
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next ele
```
````

Comment: Thank you for having a look at my problem and the advice. I have tried your solution. It is working, but still takes a long time to complete. I had the following code when the website used to be available on IE and I didn't have to work through a web driver (this is only the web scraping part):

Comment: eRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(7, 0).Row

    For Each ele In .document.all

    Select Case ele.className
    Case "day"
    RowCount = RowCount + 1
    sht.Range("B" & RowCount) = ele.innerText
    Case "units"
    If Mid(ele.NextSibling.innerText, 1, 4) = StandType Then
        sht.Range("C" & RowCount) = ele.NextSibling.innerText & " - " & ele.innerText
    End If
    End Select
    Next ele